# Regarding google places API

Tags: c#, api

What I want to know is that using Google places API. Basically I want to create a site like www.zomato.com

1) Can I show listing of all restaurants and their individual details with all the details in my city just like Google+ business page?

2) Is is possible to use this API with C#.net?

3) How much Google will charge for this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If we look at the [documentation for the Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests), we can see the format of the JSON that a request to the API returns. By using [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/), we can then easily generate a C# model for the response to a Google Places query.

```
public class Location
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Geometry
{
    public Location location { get; set; }
}

public class OpeningHours
{
    public bool open_now { get; set; }
    public List<object> weekday_text { get; set; }
}

public class Photo
{
    public int height { get; set; }
    public List<string> html_attributions { get; set; }
    public string photo_reference { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public OpeningHours opening_hours { get; set; }
    public List<Photo> photos { get; set; }
    public string place_id { get; set; }
    public double rating { get; set; }
    public string reference { get; set; }
    public string scope { get; set; }
    public List<string> types { get; set; }
    public string vicinity { get; set; }
}

public class PlacesApiQueryResponse
{
    public List<object> html_attributions { get; set; }
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

With a simple HTTP request to the Google Places API, we can then deserialize the query results using [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json).

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.GetStringAsync(string.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location={0},{1}&radius=500&type=bar&key=YourAPIKey", latitude, longitude));
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlacesApiQueryResponse>(response);
}
```