# How to get PopularTimes from Google Places Api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have searched but not getting the process to fetch PopularTimes from Google Places Api.

I tried the following:-

```
populartimes.get_id(api_key, place_id)
```

With

```
api_key str; api key from google places web service; e.g. "your-api-key"
place_id str; unique google maps id; retrievable via populartimes.get()
```

But how to use it...

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/m-wrzr/populartimes ?

Comment: @Peter B....yes ...that is implemented in pythan.....but how to implement in Asp.net Mvc with c#

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38037558/1220550 (different Google API, but the approach should work)

Comment: thanks...i tried....but that doesnot return the PopularTimes as output....

Comment: need a help if anyone knows about it....